# Is this correct usage of "designate" as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

I am aware that a *designee* is someone who is designated to do something, but I have seen some odd usage of the word *designate* because of its adjective form.

I would like to make sure I am using the word *designate* properly.
For example it is proper to say:

> He is a manager designate.

However it is not correct to say:

> He is a designate.

Is that right?

The usage I question is the following:

> Contact the Regional Manager or designate.

If the above is wrong (as I think it is) would either of the following be proper?

> Contact the Regional Manager or their designee.
>
> Contact the Regional Manager or Regional Manager designate. (This must be correct...)

Comment: As [Wikipedia]() says, a ***postpositive*** or ***postnominal adjective*** is an attributive adjective that is placed after the noun or pronoun that it modifies. Subcategory **Names of posts, ranks, etc.:** *bishop emeritus, professor emeritus, attorney general, consul general, governor general, postmaster general, surgeon general, Astronomer Royal, Princess Royal, airman basic, minister plenipotentiary, minister-president, notary public, poet laureate, president-elect, **prime minister-designate,** prince regent, sergeant major, queen consort, prince consort,...*

Comment: Side note: It seems to me that the adjective and the noun *designate* are pronounced differently.

Comment: Designate functions as a verb or a (postnominal) adjective. I've never seen a dictionary which claims that designate can function as a noun. That's why I'm looking for clarification on this point.

Comment: Just google or Ngram "or his designate". It's completely normal, although *designee* seems to be more common, which surprises me.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the word "***designate***" is being used as a noun. It is not being used as an adjective or verb.

For example we might write,

> "The ***designate*** strode down the hallway" (**Example 1**)

Any English verb which ends in "**ed**", when written in the past-tense, can be used as a noun it you omit the "**ed**" suffix.

> - "The ***work*** stood upon the dias like some sort of Greek God." (Example **2A**).
>
> The word "work" is being used as a noun.
>
> - "The ***cook*** was leaning against the wall int he alley, and smoking a cigarette, while gazing wistfully at the setting sun. (**2B**).
> - we went for a long ***walk***. (Example
>   **2C**)
> - "a ***kiss*** upon the cheek would have made her feel better; but such displays of affection were not allowed in public." (Example **2D**)
> - a ***look*** into the tank would have made most people's stomaches turn, but Susan was not a squeamish woman. (Example
>   **2E**). The word "look" is being used as a noun,  it as an adjective.
> - "Gonzalez did a good job on the car **repair**"(2F)

Likewise, "***designate***" can be used as a noun.

> - Bob badly wanted to become the new ***designate***. (Example 3A)
> - Bob badly wanted to become the new ***Attorney General Designate*** (Example 3B)

Note than in the sentence, "1 + 2 = 3", it would incorrect to say that 1 is an adjective which modifies 2. It would also be incorrect to say that 2 is an adjective which modifies 1.

Likewise, in the phrase "manager designate" the words "manager" and "designate" have equal precedence.

In a syntax tree, parse tree, or other tree diagram, it would be poor practice to have "manager" be a child of "designate" or write "designate" as a child of "manager"

There is an invisible plus sign which gives us "manager + designate"

The phrase "manager designate" being used as if it was a noun.

I reccomend that you ***not*** always analyze English sentences one word at a time.

An entire phrase of two or more words can act as a noun or act as a verb.

Likewise "manager designate" can be assigned to one single node in a tree diagram. You can draw children underneath the node if you wish to further sub-divide things. There is a branch of mathematics which is somtimes useful in linguistics.

[image: Example of tree diagrams]

Tree diagrams are a powerful tool.